# can minor differences in content cause major changes in compressed file sizes

Tags: visual-studio-2017, compression

After I shut Visual Studio down, I've been sending my main project folders each to a separate compressed file in Windows 7 using the file-system context-menu option "Send to compressed (zipped) folder".

```
My Projects
    Project1
    Project2
```

Right-click on Project2 and send its contents to a zip.

The changes to the code itself have been minimal, just a few lines of code added or removed here and there over the course of the past week. We're talking maybe 100 lines of code in total. But the resulting file sizes vary greatly, swinging back and forth between 54MB and 78MB even from one day to the next. I do not understand it.

```
54,691K
54,653K
78,518K
54,740K
78,557K
78,578K
54,803K
```

Has anyone seem similar behavior, or have an explanation for these large swings?

Comment: You can open the zip archive and Windows will tell you how details about the compression of each and every file. My guess is that you have these extraneous files being included in the 78MB variants (maybe .obj files or some other garbage)

Comment: THanks for that tip.  The contents of app.publish folder are changing, sometimes empty, sometimes 60MB of dlls.